# Yes/No :Is the number of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x] \oplus \mathbb{Z_5}$ and $\mathbb{Z_3} \oplus \mathbb{Z_5} $ are same?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the number  of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x] \oplus \mathbb{Z_5}$ and $\mathbb{Z_3} \oplus \mathbb{Z_5} $ the same?

My attempt :  I think they're the same  because the number of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x] \oplus \mathbb{Z_5}=2$

Since $\{0\} \oplus \mathbb{Z_5}$  and $\mathbb{Z_3}  \oplus \{0\}$ are the prime ideals of both $\mathbb{Z}_3[x] \oplus \mathbb{Z_5}$ and $\mathbb{Z_3} \oplus \mathbb{Z_5} $

Is this true  ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $x\Bbb Z_3[x]$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ then $x\Bbb Z_3[x]\oplus \Bbb Z_5$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb Z_3[x]\oplus\Bbb Z_5$. So there's at least three of them.

Indeed $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ has infinitely many prime ideals; therefore
so does $\Bbb Z_3[x]\oplus\Bbb Z_5$.